# How to change value of an object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following statment that if isdefault is true to this collection i need to set each object isDefault property to false.

```
  custHead.lstCustomziation.Where(x => x.IsDefaultSelected == true).Select(x=>{x.IsDefaultSelected=false});

lstCustomziation  is a collection.
```

Comment: what about .ForEach extension?

Comment: LINQ = Language-Integrated **Query**

Comment: Just return the updated object in `Select`. What's the problem? Technically you can do this, but - as pointed out - it's abusing the concept of LINQ  somewhat. By the way, the MoreLINQ library - https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ - has a `Pipe` method. At least it makes the intention explicit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LINQ is for querying. You should use a `foreach` loop to make changes:

```
foreach (var item in custHead.lstCustomziation.Where(x => x.IsDefaultSelected))
{
    item.IsDefaultSelected = false;
}
```

That said, if `IsDefaultSelected` is `false` for the other items anyway, it may be simpler just to unconditionally set it:

```
foreach (var item in custHead.lstCustomziation)
{
    item.IsDefaultSelected = false;
}
```

Comment: which approach would be faster in this scenario, curiously?

Comment: @Jonesy: If `IsDefaultSelected` is a trivial property (so doesn't check whether or not it needs to fire change notifications etc) then I'd expect the latter approach to be faster.

Answer (score 5):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  You can get a list of the items you want to change and *then* update using a normal loop:

```
var list = custHead.lstCustomziation.Where(x => x.IsDefaultSelected == true)

foreach(var item in list)
    item.IsDefaultSelected=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Q of LINQ says, LINQ is designed for queries, not updates.

Just enumerate the LINQ result and apply your update.

Answer (score 0):

Linq may have been initially created for querying but it has evolved and is used as functional programming methods, equivalents to "map", "reduce", and "filter" used in other languages.

In your example I would suggest:

```
var list = custHead.lstCustomziation.Where(x => x.IsDefaultSelected == true)
            .Select(x=> TransformItem(x));

private XType TransformItem(XType item){
    item.IsDefaultSelected=false;
    return item;
}
```