# C# Lambda expression update value to nullable field

Tags: c#, lambda

Please take a look at code below:

```
SomeList.Where(x => !x.Name.Equals("NO")).All(x => x.flag=true);
```

`SomeList` is a `ICollection`

For each of the object in `SomeList`, if the `Name` is not `NO`, `flag` of the object should be updated to be `true`. Now the problem is the `flag` is `bool?`

How should I assign value to the `flag` in such lambda expression?

Comment: Why are you trying to use LINQ to perform mutations anyway? Just use `foreach`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781979/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are essentially trying to do is avoid using `foreach` which is fruitless business. Alexander's answer uses `ForEach` extension method, but then you also must materialize a list using `ToList` method.

Most elegant approach is to just use `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var item in SomeList.Where(x => !x.Name.Equals("NO")))
    item.flag = true;
```

---

If you really want to have an functional programming style of invoking an action on all members of a collection, either write your own extension method or use [Ix.NET which already provides such helper extensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main).

```
var n = 0;
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Do(x => n += x)
```

It provides following overloads

```
IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> onNext)
IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> onNext, Action onCompleted)
IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> onNext, Action<Exception> onError)
IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> onNext, Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted)
IEnumerable<TSource> Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IObserver<TSource> observer)
```

Comment: The reason for you to suggest to use `foreach` is because of performance issue or it is not possible to achieve my objective using `Lambda expression`?

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you want using standard .NET libraries. I think that it is more elegant to use `foreach` that add `ToList` just for sake of calling `ForEach` extension method. Also, I don't want the collection to be enumerated two times, just because I thought `ForEach` looks nicer (first time to materialize List, second time to invoke your function). Alternative is to write your own `ForEach` or use `Ix.NET` which provides such cool extension methods.