# Using linq to iterate through winform menuitems and change a property value

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, menuitem

I have a context menu. I went to iterate through all the menu items and disable or enable them based on a some boolean value.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
contextMenu.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().Select(x =>
{
   x.Enabled = someValue; 
   return x;
});
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?  Compile error?  No results?  What do you expect `return x;` to do?

Comment: I have a menu item in the context menu. However it is never disabled, even when someValue is false. I put a break point in the lambda expression and it's never getting hit. It seems like the cast isn't working right. However, I know of no alternatives to get this to work (Hence why I posted here).

Comment: Selman22's answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple `foreach` loop for update your values, `LINQ` is for *querying*

```
foreach(var item in contextMenu.MenuItems.OfType<MenuItem>())
{
    item.Enabled = someValue;
}
```

Comment: I understand it can be done with a foreach loop, however, I want to know if there is a linq expression to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: No, there is no method for update in `LINQ`.And `LINQ` is not designed for that, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21782011/3010968) of Jon Skeet.

Comment: I did something similar - using a for loop after the LINQ expression to iterate over the result list and update each item in the list. My boss told me not to use the for loop and instead change the existing LINQ expression to also update each element.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing is the `ForEach` method on `List<T>`. I don't this that it's technically considered LINQ and unlike the core LINQ to Objects methods it's not part of `IEnumerable<T>`. Anyway, I'm guessing you'll prefer it to a traditional `foreach` loop since it looks like any other LINQ query using method syntax.

```
contextMenu.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Enabled = someValue);
```

Comment: You should use `ToList`, `Cast` doesn't return `List<T>`

Comment: @Selman22 ty. I updated with that edit. To that point, I would not suggest actually using this approach over a normal foreach as it iterates the collection twice.